# Use different interfaces for DNS and Network

Tags: macos, network

I would like all DNS to use my en6 USB ethernet interface.

And all other network traffic to use en0 wifi.

How can I do so?

I have been exploring `dnsmasq` and `bind`, but don't see how to use them for this. Hopefully it's possible without any third party apps.

(macOS Catalina 10.15.2)

Comment: It's no problem to (mis-)configure *dnsmasq/bind* (or *pf*) like this. But the *Gustinet* you have in mind won't work at all considering your network setup in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381503/use-hostnames-from-second-network-interface). Yesterday your USB ethernet interface didn't have any Internet access (**=probably no global DNS**). This clearly is a **[tripleXtripleY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your various network/dns questions? What's the major problem with your university's network?

Comment: @klanomath there's no internet access from one network, and no access to computers I need from the other (that has internet)

Comment: @klanomath the USB ethernet does have global DNS, I think it just has firewall rules to prevent my macbook (and most devices connected to it) from accessing the internet through it.

Comment: As yesterday: To answer your question more details are required: `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -nr`! ;-)

Comment: I wish I could multi up vote @klanomath on this being a Triple X, Triple Y problem.  Your Uni obviously has two networks they wish to keep separate but you're trying to bodge some solution together to make them talk to each other.  *What exactly do you want to accomplish?*

Comment: @Allan I want to ssh into hosts on the internet-less network, but have internet connection so that I can keep using the internet (for example, to google errors that come up during the ssh session)

Comment: You already *can* do that.  Traffic meant for the WiFi network  (plus Internet) will go through WiFi.  Traffic meant to go to the private network will go through Ethernet as answered in your [existing question](https://bit.ly/2UB4LUS).  Your problem is DNS.  As in the first question, were you able to ping hosts on both networks?

Comment: You might want to read this:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413646/107777  I know the answer to this because I had the *exact same question* for my own lab setup.  My recommendation to you is to edit the hosts file because it's one computer.  Set up another split horizion DNS if you will have many computers that need to "see" both networks.

Comment: @Allan I was able to DNS resolve all hosts on the wired network, but only ping local computers and not ping the internet

Comment: I didn't ask about DNS resolve.  I asked about pining the hosts.  Use their individual IPs

Comment: @Allan I can only ping local computers, but not the internet (using the wired connection)

Comment: @Allan your recommendation to edit `hosts` on my own computer indeed works, but is inconvenient for me because I would have to add x-hundred hostnames and then whenever their IPs change I must manually update them. That's why I want to use the provided DNS for them

Comment: You would have to do that with the answer that has you create a DNS service.  How is it going to auto-update?  Where are the hostnames → IPs going to come from?  It doesn't show up magically.  But on a side note, are these servers you're connecting to?  If so, why would their address change?  That's not best practice

Comment: Given that the wired network has no internet, I wouldn't expect you to ping anything from the Internet.  What about WiFi, can you ping there?  Make sure *both* network connections are up.  You also need to provide the info asked by klanomath.  What IP address spaces are you using?